# Scaling ImageButton basing on screen size

Tags: java, android, image-scaling, autoscaling, android-imagebutton

In my application i can scaling an ImageView using this class

`public class resizeAvatar extends View {

```
private final Drawable sfondoAvatar;

public resizeAvatar(Context context) {
    super(context);

    sfondoAvatar = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_voice);
    setBackgroundDrawable(sfondoAvatar);

}

public resizeAvatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    sfondoAvatar = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_voice);
    setBackgroundDrawable(sfondoAvatar);
}

public resizeAvatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    sfondoAvatar = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_voice);
    setBackgroundDrawable(sfondoAvatar);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                                   int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * sfondoAvatar.getIntrinsicHeight() / sfondoAvatar.getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

}
`

And writing in the layout:

`<com.myapp.app.resizeAvatar
        android:id="@+id/mainvoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>`

But in this way i can't have the onClick event.. i need do the same but using an ImageButton.. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity where you include this view and in the onCreate method do the following:

```
resizeAvatar myMainvoice  = (resizeAvatar) v.findViewById(R.id.mainvoice);
myMainVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
               //place your on click logic here 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yesss it works!! i didn't think about this solution. Thank you!